# Is it possible to use where in with if not exist select statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, where-in

I would like to update table comparing with multiple values.

However, the command completed successfully without insert data if one of them in condition satisfies, I would like to insert one another value if mid is not in the table.

Is it possible to extend the SQL query more than as follows?

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM membership WHERE mid IN (513, 761, ...)))
    INSERT INTO membership (id, uId, rId, gId, assignedBy .... )
    VALUES (1, 226, 5, 1, 5, 3), 
           (1, 227, 7, 6, 1, 3)
        ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend you look at `MERGE` instead of `INSERT`.

Comment: I create the mid column by concat and I have more columns to insert, the table is an example. Thanks

Comment: Your `INSERT` query does not specify a value for the `mid` column. How is it populated? Is it an `IDENTITY` column or provided in your input data?

Comment: I added mid column and updated mid data using the query   
 update membership SET mid = CONCAT(uid, gid, rid)
in order to compare if exist

Comment: I see no reason here to use `MERGE` instead of `INSERT`

Comment: Now that I posted an answer, I see that `MERGE` would probably be less complicated

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but let me pose this answer:

If you want to insert records that don't exist based on a key columns, use this pattern:

```
-- First set up a virtual table called SRC that contains our manual values
-- This is called a CTE (Common Table Expression)
WITH SRC AS
(
    SELECT * FROM 
    (
        VALUES 
           (1, 226, 5, 1, 5, 3), 
           (1, 227, 7, 6, 1, 3)

    ) as T (id, uId, rId, gId, assignedBy, mid)
)

-- select only those values that don't exist in the target and insert them
INSERT INTO membership (id, uId, rId, gId, assignedBy,mid)
SELECT id, uId, rId, gId, assignedBy,mid FROM SRC
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM membership TGT WHERE TGT.mid = SRC.mid)
```

Granted the `MERGE` version of this would probably be a but simpler. You could also rewrite this in many other ways - you could exclude already existing rows in the CTE

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It would be greatly helpful for me. My apologies the unclear question. I would like to insert with the unique id of the membership table. The variable (1, 226, 5, 1, 5, 3), (1, 227, 7, 6, 1, 3)  returned from UI .
I am going to try to manipulate the query to match my request.

Comment: I am struggling to adjust the query into my request. Is it possible to check not exist only a few values such as "uid, rid, gid " then, insert all value (id, uId, rId, gId, assignedBy) ?

Comment: It’s still unclear what your request is. My solution only checks one value. If you want to check more values just extend the Where clause inside the not exists.